# Tensor product $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z} \otimes M$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Is it true that if $M$ is a torsion abelian group, then $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}  \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M =0$? If it is, why?

Comment: Try to use the fact that $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ is divisible: any element $x$ can be written $x=ny$.

Comment: I know, but how could help me that? I know if $M$ is a torsion abelian group, there exists $n$ natural such that $a^n=0$  for every $a$. But I don't know about the fact that $na=0$.

Comment: It's the same thing (except that it is $a^n=1$ and not $a^n=0$). You write $a^n$ when the law of $M$ is written as a multiplication, and $na$ when it is written as an addition, but they are the same concept. If $M$ is a torsion group, $na=0$ for some $n$, or $a^n=1$ for some $n$ if $M$ is multiplicative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element of $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} M$ can be written as a sum of elements of the form $[r]\otimes m$, where $[r]$ represents the equivilence class containing $r\in \mathbb Q$ in the quotient module.  However, if $m$ is torsion, there exists an $n$ such that $nm=0$.  Then inside the tensor product, $$[r]\otimes m=[nr/n]\otimes m=[r/n]n\otimes m=[r/n]\otimes nm=[r/n]\otimes 0 = 0.$$

If every $m\in M$ is torsion, then every element of $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z}M$ is thus a sum of elements that are all equal to $0$.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the only thing we used here about $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is that every element can be written as a multiple of $n$, and so the same argument would show that $\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z} M=0$.